# Don't make stats public when uploading to YouTube via API

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm uploading to YouTube using Python via [an officially provided script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video).

The default settings for my channel (defined on youtube.com/upload_defaults when logged in) have **Make video statistics on the watch page publicly visible** set to disabled.

The response contains the following

```
'status': {
  'publicStatsViewable': True,
```

and the **edit** page (**advanced** tab) of the video reveals that it is in fact [turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyWTP.png).

How to disable publicly visible statistics for a video when uploading via API with Python?

I assume something in this part of the upload script needs to be changed but it is unclear to me which:

```
body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type:

```
   status=dict(
      privacyStatus="private"
    )
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the privacy of the video, only of the statistics of the video

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to modify the body to include `status.publicStatsViewable`, set to `False`. Just add the following line to the `body` construction block:

```
      publicStatsViewable=False,
```

so that it looks like:

```
body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      publicStatsViewable=False,
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )
```

Note that I only tested with the value being a boolean `False`. I did not test it with using a string.